# Odoo Custom Shipping Module

Tags: api, odoo

I want to develop a custom shipping module for Odoo, but I can't find the documentation for it and all the shipping source is Enterprise, so I can't see it without paying.

[image]

I found the Odoo Developer guid here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/

I found how to create a module: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html

I found the Guide for Payment processors: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/ecommerce/shopper_experience/payment.html

Where is the documentation for shipping connectors?
I know it can be done, there are third party shipping connectors on the odoo marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Odoo `delivery` module:

> ```
> In order to add your own external provider, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create your model MyProvider that _inherit 'delivery.carrier'
> 2. Extend the selection of the field "delivery_type" with a pair
>    ('<my_provider>', 'My Provider')
> 3. Add your methods:
>    <my_provider>_rate_shipment
>    <my_provider>_send_shipping
>    <my_provider>_get_tracking_link
>    <my_provider>_cancel_shipment
>    _<my_provider>_get_default_custom_package_code
>    (they are documented hereunder)
> ```

To implement your own shipping connector, I would suggest you to start looking into this module. It is from community so already available for all community users.